# Drupal8 retain quick edit functionality when inserting content from node variable

Tags: twig, markup, drupal-8

I have this markup in my twig file.

```
<div class="post-title-block ilb">
  <h2 class="thin">{{ node.title.value }}</h2>
</div>
```

I would like to retain Drupal quick edit functionality.
Where how how to I wrap {{ attributes }}, {{ title_prefix }}, {{ title_suffix }} etc.. ?

My twig file lives in templates/content/node--posts-full.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated a node template, which means you will add {{attributes}} to a block element that surrounds the field content, and add the prefixes just after the same element so that the quickedit module can inject it's markup towards the top of the block.

Presuming the above is your template, you could do:

```
<section{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
    [you could wrap an actual title here...]
  {{ title_suffix }}
  <div class="post-title-block ilb">
    <h2 class="thin">{{ node.title.value }}</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```